# Default value for site-column? SP2010

Tags: 2010, site-column, default-value

Is there any way to set a default value for a site-column with type "Full HTML content with formatting and constraints for publishing" in SharePoint 2010?

The site-column is used for a PageLayout for an Enterprise Wiki.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you could do it either by using event receiver or by **Default** node inside **Field** node:

```
  <Field
       ID="{f4c96457-f8e8-4544-8165-a164123db510}"
       Name="testColumn"
       DisplayName="test Column"
       Type="Note"
       RichText="TRUE" 
       RichTextMode="FullHtml"
       Required="FALSE"
       Group="Custom Site Columns">
    <Default><![CDATA[<h1>test!</h1>]]></Default>
  </Field>
```

I've just tested it and it works. This is the code you'll have to include in your Elements.xml or Schema.xml depending on the location of your field definition.